# Java: Retrieve random, non-repeating Elements from array One-by-One

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have an Array containing a set of Points and a Timer.

I want to get a random Point from the Array with each Action Event fired from the Timer. The catch here is that I need a different one with every Iteration, that means I don't wanna get the same Point twice.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: create an `List` with all indexes from the array. get a random element from the List, remove this number from the List and repeat it.

Comment: Copy your array into an `ArrayList`, call `Collections.shuffle` with that list as an argument, iterate through the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a List, `shuffle` it, then iterate.

```
List<Point> pointsList = Arrays.asList(yourArray);
long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(pointsList, new Random(seed));
```

Comment: If you use raw types Lists, then you can simply remove the generic <Point>. The logic remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for your Solution, it's simple and works as intended!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29), and you can get a `List` backed by an array with [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29). Something like,

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

which will display the array `arr` in a random order (with non-repeating elements).

Answer (score 0):

Despite the way to shuffle it you could also create a simple list with each index of the array. A tiny example could be working like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(numbers.length);
    for(int i = 0;i<numbers.length;++i) {
        list.add(i);
    }
}

private static int returnRandomNumber(List<Integer> list) {
    Random r = new Random();
    if(list.size() == 0) {
        return -1; // maybe throw an exception
    }
    int index = r.nextInt(list.size());
    int number = list.get(index);
    list.remove(index);
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's a bit of an overkill though ;) Collections.shuffle() and iterating through the list works just fine.